# Combining/"beautify" these 2 functions to use 1 class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How can I combine the 2 functions below to use only 1 class? Will be very convenient down the road with how I'm using them. I want to combine the functionality of allowing 3 selections per dropdown but combine `.multiselect1` and `.multiselect2` to just `.multiselect`

Here's the fiddle of these dropdown widgets I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/124/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".multiselect1").multiselect({
                header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
                click: function (event, ui) {   
                    var number1 = $("#MDCselect").children(":checked").length;
                    if (ui.checked && (number1 >= 3)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                selectedList: 5
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".multiselect2").multiselect({
                header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
                click: function (event, ui) {
                  var number2 = $("#Clinicalselect").children(":checked").length;
                    if (ui.checked && (number2 >= 3)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                selectedList: 5
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it as follows ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/127/)):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".multiselect").multiselect({
            header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
            click: function (event, ui) {   
                var number = $(this).children(":checked").length;
                if (ui.checked && (number >= 3)) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            selectedList: 5
        });
    });
```

A slight modification to the html was required: setting both multiselect classes to `multiselect`.

One question, however. It says that you can select up to 5 areas, but the limit is set to 3. Is this just a symptom of giving a concise example?

Comment: Yeah its 5 in my project. Changed just making things quicker when testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="mp">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" class="mp">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

And javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mp").multiselect({
                header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
                click: function (event, ui) {   
                    var number1 = $(this).children(":checked").length;
                    if (ui.checked && (number1 >= 3)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                selectedList: 5
            });
        });
```

Checkout this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/126/)

Answer (score 1):

See the updated fiddle. You can use $(this)

http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/125/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".multiselect").multiselect({
            header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
            click: function (event, ui) {

                var number1 = $(this).children(":checked").length;
                if (ui.checked && (number1 >= 3)) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            selectedList: 5
        });
    });
```